# Decisions based on variable passed to function

Tags: python, function

I am a new Python 3 user and need to make the following work somehow.  I don't know how to correctly take actions based on the variable `operation`.

```
def arith(x, y, operation):
    if operation == add:
        return x + y
    if operation == mult:
        return x * y
print(arith(x = 2, y = 3, operation = add))
print(arith(x = 2, y = 3, operation = mult))
```

I get the following error message:

print(arith(x = 2, y = 3, operation = add))
NameError: name 'add' is not defined

I have looked but cannot find this type of question answered

Comment: What are you expecting "add" to be? Is it supposed to be a string?

Comment: Use 'add' instead of add

Answer (score 1):

```
def arith(x, y, operation):
    if operation == 'add':
        return x + y
    if operation == 'mult':
        return x * y
arith(2, 3, 'add')
arith(2, 3, 'mult')
```

The problem is that add and mult are not defined. By wrapping them each in quotes, 'add' and 'mult', you define them as string.

Check out [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html) documentation on strings for more information.